# Quantum statistics of a particle in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, quantum-statistics

Let us consider the statistical physics of a single particle (without spin) moving in a magnetic field described by a vector potential $\vec{A}$ at a finite temperature $1/\beta$ on a $2$-dimensional plane with a Hamiltonian $H\left((\vec{p}-e\vec{A}),\vec{x}\right)$.

In the classical regime, it can be argued that the statistics is not affected by the magnetic field since the classicial partition function
\begin{eqnarray}
Z_\text{cl}[\vec{A}]&=&\int d\vec{x}\int d\vec{p}\exp\left[-\beta H\left(\vec{p}-e\vec{A},\vec{x}\right)\right]\nonumber\\
&=&\int d\vec{x}\int d\tilde{p}\exp\left[-\beta H\left(\tilde{p},\vec{x}\right)\right]\nonumber\\
&=&Z_\text{cl}[0], 
\end{eqnarray}
where a change of the dumb variable $\tilde{p}=\vec{p}-e\vec{A}$ has been done.

However, in the quantum statistics, the calculation of partition function is different due to $[\vec{x},\vec{p}]\neq0$. My question is whether there is simple e.g. exactly-solvable, single-particle (spinless) quantum mechanics where a nonzero magnetic field can affect its quantum partition function: $Z_\text{quan}[A]\neq Z_\text{quan}[0]$?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{p} \rightarrow \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{A}$ is not just changing to a "dumb variable".

The *canonical momentum* $\mathbf{p}_{\mathrm{c}}$ is defined as: 
$$\mathbf{p}_{\mathrm{c}} =  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{r}}}= m\dot{\mathbf{r}} + q \mathbf{A}, $$
where $m\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ is the *physical* momentum, i.e. the one that corresponds to the change in momentm in Newton's second law.

When you have a particle coupling to an electro-magnetic field, the *short-cut* to the get the correct Hamiltonian is to replace the physical momentum $\mathbf{p}$ in the *free* Hamiltonian ($p^2/2m$) to the canonical momentum:

$$ H = \frac{(\mathbf{p}-q\mathbf{A})^2}{2m} + q\phi(\mathbf{r}),$$
where $\phi$ could be, for instance, an electric potential.

Expanding the Hamiltonian, you get a $\mathbf{p^2}$ term, a $\propto \mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{A}$ term and a $\mathbf{A}^2$ term. All of them modify your original Hamitlonian and lead to a different statistic.

In the specific case of a static magnetic field, so $\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{r}$, the two $\mathbf{A}$ dependent terms are known as the *linear* and *quadratic* Zeeman effects.